# Use variables to change a Timer object's delay dynamically

Tags: flash, variables, timer

I am attempting to make a timer that automatically resets itself when a certain variable is reached. After it is set with a certain variable, it will then run the Function on the TimerEvent with the new variable and keep doing that. I tried building it, but I feel like i'm missing something. Here is what i'm attempting to achieve.

```
var _timerVar:Timer = new Timer(_ticks);
var _ticks = 4000
var _varToChange = 1;

_timerVar.addEventListener(TIMER.TimerEvent,changeTimer)
function changeTimer():void{
   if(_varToChange == 1){
       _ticks = 4500
   } else if(_varToChange == 2){
       _ticks = 5000
   } else if(_varToChange == 3){
       _ticks = 6000
   }
   _timerVar.reset();
   _timerVar = new Timer(_ticks);
   _timerVar.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you just need to add this line inside your **changeTimer()** function just after instantiating a new **Timer** object:

```
_timerVar.addEventListener(TIMER.TimerEvent,changeTimer);
```

A better approach is to just reset the timer and change its delay instead of instantiating a new one everytime. You can use this inside your **changeTimer**() function:

```
_timerVar.reset();
_timerVar.delay = _ticks;
_timerVar.start();
```

Cheers!